# Getting UIPicker to appear when user selects a UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, datepicker

I have a simple UITextField called month where I get users to simply enter the month they want via the keyboard that comes up. I would now like it for them to be able to use a UIPickerDate (or UIPicker) to make this selection instead. So when they press on the text field, a mini UIPicker appears and they make there selection, press anywhere on the screen and the picker disappears.

Does anyone know how to do this or has any suggestions? I am pretty new to programming and have looked at other answers but everyone seems to be referring to this being done in a table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `inputView` property on the `UITextField` to be an instance of `UIDatePicker`. When the instance of `UITextField` becomes the first responder, the picker view will be displayed with the standard keyboard animation.

```
// Assume that self.monthTextField and self.datePicker 
// are properties of the view controller class
self.monthTextField.inputView = self.datePicker;
```

As for dismissing, that depends on the context. If there are more text fields to populate, consider adding a `UIToolbar` as the `inputAccessoryView` of `self.monthTextField`. Then you can add something like a `UIBarButtonItem` to make the next text field the first responder, similar to how the standard keyboard provides a Next button.